# Google Tag Manager and Goals

Tags: analytics

I know how to create and apply tags for eccommerce within Google Tag Manager. Do I also need to set up goals in analytics to track revenue/transaction? If it's not necessary, is there any benefit to also setting up goals or can this all be tracked through Google Analytics and recorded because of the GTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would/should set up goals in analytics to track revenue and transactions. GTM won't be able to tell what are goals or not, so that 'interpretation' would be done in GA.

Answer (score 0):

It is also useful for conversion funnel analysis. You can analyze every step before transaction.

Comment: I have bee learning about these! Can you recommend or give an example of useful conversion funnels you have used or know of for transactions?

Comment: The simplest example of funnel is cart - checkout page - thank you page. Also there might be some steps in checkout process.